# Passing a table to a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with  20 billion rows. Table does not have any indexes as it was created on fly  for doing bulk insert operation. The table is being used in a stored procedure which does the following operation

```
Delete A
from master a 
inner join (Select distinct Col from TableB ) b
on A.Col = B.Col

Insert into master 
Select *
from tableB
group by col1,col2,col3
```

`TableB` is the one which has 20 billion rows.  I don't want to execute SP directly because it might take days to complete the execution. `Master` is also a huge table and has clustered index on `Col`

1. Can i pass chunks of rows to the stored procedure and perform the operation.This might reduce the log file growth. If yes how can i do that
2. Should i create clustered index on the table and execute the SP which might be little faster but then again i  think creating CI on a huge table might take 10 hours to complete.

Or is there any way to perform this operation fast

Comment: If you're doing insert operations, indexes will slow you down.  Remove  all your indexes on Master before running your insert.

Comment: I can't drop  `indexes` on `master` table as it contains historical data having close to 50 billion rows

Comment: You can do the delete, blow away the indexes, and do the insert, then recreate the indexes.  Depending on the number of indexes, that will be significantly faster than inserting without removing. Also, that subselect on your delete is worthless and will slow down your query.  Just join straight to `TableB` and dont call distinct.

Comment: Any thing you do with 10 billion records will be slow.  The real priority is to make sure you have a way to show your progress.  Writing a loop that takes a chunk of records at a time then reports progress is a good way to go.  You ought to take 1M records and make a restartable test to work out your fastest options.

Comment: The table partitioning was meant exactly for this kind of scenario. Load a small table with data and switch into the large table, speeds up things enormously. Same for deletes.

Comment: @dean : Can it be done on standard edition ?

Comment: No, it can't. But with 20 bill rows per table you enter the problems you can't solve with the standard ed. I do understand it's probably not your decision to make, but nevertheless.

Answer (score 3):

I've used a method similar to [this one](http://sqlserverplanet.com/data-warehouse/transferring-large-amounts-of-data-using-batch-inserts).  I'd recommend putting your DB into Bulk Logged recovery mode instead of Full recovery mode if you can.

Blog entry reproduced below to future proof it.

> Below is a technique used to transfer a large amount of records from
>   one table to another. This scales pretty well for a couple reasons.
>   First, this will not fill up the entire log prior to committing the
>   transaction. Rather, it will populate the table in chunks of 10,000
>   records. Second, it’s generally much quicker. You will have to play
>   around with the batch size. Sometimes it’s more efficient at 10,000,
>   sometimes 500,000, depending on the system.
>
> If you do not need to insert into an existing table and just need a
>   copy of the table, it is better to do a `SELECT INTO`. However for this
>   example, we are inserting into an existing table.
>
> Another trick you should do is to change the recovery model of the
>   database to simple. This way, there will be much less logging in the
>   transaction log.
>
> The `WITH (TABLOCK)` below only works in SQL 2008.
>
> ```
> DECLARE @BatchSize INT = 10000
>
> WHILE 1 = 1
> BEGIN
>
>     INSERT INTO [dbo].[Destination] --WITH (TABLOCK)  -- Uncomment for 2008
>     (
>         FirstName
>         ,LastName
>         ,EmailAddress
>         ,PhoneNumber
>     )
>     SELECT TOP(@BatchSize) 
>         s.FirstName
>         ,s.LastName
>         ,s.EmailAddress
>         ,s.PhoneNumber
>     FROM [dbo].[SOURCE] s
>     WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
>         SELECT 1
>         FROM dbo.Destination
>         WHERE PersonID = s.PersonID
>     )
>
>     IF @@ROWCOUNT < @BatchSize BREAK
>
> END
> ```
>
> With the above example, it is important to have at least a non
>   clustered index on `PersonID` in both tables.
>
> Another way to transfer records is to use multiple threads. Specifying
>   a range of records as such:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO [dbo].[Destination]
>     (
>         FirstName
>         ,LastName
>         ,EmailAddress
>         ,PhoneNumber
>     )
>     SELECT TOP(@BatchSize) 
>         s.FirstName
>         ,s.LastName
>         ,s.EmailAddress
>         ,s.PhoneNumber
>     FROM [dbo].[SOURCE] s
>     WHERE PersonID BETWEEN 1 AND 5000
> GO
> INSERT INTO [dbo].[Destination]
>     (
>         FirstName
>         ,LastName
>         ,EmailAddress
>         ,PhoneNumber
>     )
>     SELECT TOP(@BatchSize) 
>         s.FirstName
>         ,s.LastName
>         ,s.EmailAddress
>         ,s.PhoneNumber
>     FROM [dbo].[SOURCE] s
>     WHERE PersonID BETWEEN 5001 AND 10000
> ```
>
> For super fast performance however, I’d recommend using SSIS.
>   Especially in SQL Server 2008. We recently transferred 17 million
>   records in 5 minutes with an SSIS package executed on the same server
>   as the two databases it transferred between.
>
> SQL Server 2008 SQL Server 2008 has made changes with regards to it’s
>   logging mechanism when inserting records. Previously, to do an insert
>   that was minimally logged, you would have to perform a `SELECT.. INTO`.
>   Now, you can perform a minimally logged insert if you can lock the
>   table you are inserting into. The example below shows an example of
>   this. The exception to this rule is if you have a clustered index on
>   the table AND the table is not empty. If the table is empty and you
>   acquire a table lock and you have a clustered index, it will be
>   minimally logged. However if you have data in the table, the insert
>   will be logged. Now if you have a non clustered index on a heap and
>   you acquire a table lock then only the non clustered index will be
>   logged. It is always better to drop indexes prior to inserting
>   records.
>
> To determine the amount of logging you can use the following statement
>
> ```
>  SELECT * FROM ::fn_dblog(NULL, NULL)
> ```

Credit for above goes to Derek Dieter at SQL Server Planet.

Answer (score 1):

If you're dead set on passing a table to your stored procedure, [you can pass a table-valued parameter to a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/passing-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008/).  You might have better luck with some other approaches suggested, like partitioning.  Select distinct on a table with 20 billion rows might be part of the problem.  I wonder if some very basic tuning wouldn't help, too:

```
Delete A
from master a 
where exists (select 1 from TableB b where b.Col = a.Col)
```